# Could not find configuration node: federatedAuthentication/sharedTransformations/setIdpClaim

Tags: federated-authentication

The configuration for federated authentication, was working fine with the Sitecore version 8.2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentDelivery or ContentManagement">
    <settings>
      <setting name="ClientId" value="MyValue" />
      <setting name="AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}" />
      <setting name="Tenant" value="MyValue" />
      <setting name="PostLogoutRedirectURI" value="MyValue" />
      <setting name="RedirectURI" value="MyValue" />
    </settings>
    <pipelines>
      <owin.identityProviders>
        <processor type="MyValue.Foundation.AzureAD.CustomAzureADIdentityProvider, MyValue.Foundation.AzureAD" resolve="true" />
      </owin.identityProviders>
    </pipelines>
    <federatedAuthentication>
      <identityProviders hin="list:AddIdentityProvider">
        <identityProvider id="xp0.sc.azureAD" 
         type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
          <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
          <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
          <caption>Sign-in with Azure Active Directory</caption>
          <domain>sitecore</domain>
          <icon>/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/Images/24x24/msazure.png</icon>
          <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">

            <transformation name="Idp Claim" ref="federatedAuthentication/sharedTransformations/setIdpClaim" />

            <transformation name="Transform to Sitecore DEV Role" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
              <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                <claim name="groups" value="2b53eea7-21e2-49bf-9e9c-607904029ff6" />
              </sources>
              <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                <claim name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" value="Sitecore\Developer" />
              </targets>
              <keepSource>true</keepSource>
            </transformation>
          </transformations>
        </identityProvider>
      </identityProviders>

      <propertyInitializer type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.PropertyInitializer, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
        <maps hint="list">
          <map name="email claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
            <data hint="raw:AddData">
              <!--claim name-->
              <source name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" />
              <!--property name-->
              <target name="Email" />
            </data>
          </map>

      <map name="Name claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
        <data hint="raw:AddData">
          <!--claim name-->
          <source name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname" />
          <!--property name-->
          <target name="Name" />
        </data>
      </map>

    </maps>
  </propertyInitializer>
  <identityProvidersPerSites>
    <mapEntry name="all" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
      <sites hint="list">
        <site>shell</site>
        <site>login</site>
        <site>admin</site>
        <site>service</site>
        <site>modules_shell</site>
        <site>modules_website</site>
        <site>website</site>
        <site>scheduler</site>
        <site>system</site>
        <site>publisher</site>
      </sites>

      <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
        <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='xp0.sc.azureAD']" />
      </identityProviders>

      <externalUserBuilder type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
        <param desc="isPersistentUser">true</param>
      </externalUserBuilder>
    </mapEntry>
  </identityProvidersPerSites>
</federatedAuthentication>
```

When i tried same configuration on Sitecore 9.1, i am getting below exception at transformation of idp claim.

> Could not find configuration node:
>   federatedAuthentication/sharedTransformations/setIdpClaim

Any resolution?

Comment: The entire authentication layer has changed in Sitecore 9.1.

Comment: i am also facing the same issue. i have added Above solution line then i got **"Empty strings are not allowed."
Parameter name: name** <transformation name="Idp Claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SetIdpClaimTransform, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" /> please help i am using sitecore 9.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I gone through into the greater details of the issue and found the solution.

I replaced the configuration for Idp Claim transformation from

```
<transformation name="Idp Claim" ref="federatedAuthentication/sharedTransformations/setIdpClaim" />
```

to

```
<transformation name="Idp Claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SetIdpClaimTransform, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" />
```

This resolved my issue.